# Displaying ontologies in a web page using autocomplete

Tags: jena

I have a requirement to show the words from an OWL file in a web page as an autocomplete field.
So when the user types in a term, it should query the ontology file created using Protege and show the matches in a autocomplete text field.

How can I do this? Is this possible using the Jena API?
Can someone provide examples? I am completely new to Ontology.

Comment: AFAIK Jena API itself has nothing to do with web technology. You need to be familiar with web technologies like JavaScript, Ajax and in case of Jena Java on server side (+ servlets + kind of servlet container like Tomcat) to be able to accomplish this requirement. Of course other technologies can also be used. Jena itself is only responsible for retrieving and manipulating datas from/to RDF, it may have services to be used on server side.

Comment: thanks Bela..i know ajax,javascript...but i am not able to find any straight forward example for reading data from owl file

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in multiple ways:

1. You can have a Web service (REST API) which accepts a keyword and it responses with an auto-complete field. here web service can use Jena API (SPARQL) to make a query to ontology.
2. you can query ontology using [link](http://jowl.ontologyonline.org/) if your data is in the form of RDF then use [link](http://code.google.com/p/rdfquery/)

SPARQL query language(it's part of Jena API) helps in retrieving data from ontology.

Hope this information helps.

Comment: Thanks Swamy will go though your Suggestions